# Audio only on honker after upgrade to 12.10/13.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm using a Dell Optiplex 980.  Under 12.04, the line speakers worked fine, but after upgrading to 12.10 yesterday, the only audio output was through the built-in PC speaker with nothing going to the speakers connected via analog port.  Thinking this might have been a problem with 12.10, I just kept going and went to 13.04.  Same problem.

Going into sound settings only shows "Speakers/Built-in Audio".  snd-hda-intel is loaded, but I don't know why PulseAudio isn't seeing it.  Argh!

Comment: Do you have another sound card build in? other than the integrated?

Answer (score 0):

What you can try:

Open a new Terminal window using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Type in `alsamixer`. This will open the sound Equalizer.

Now press <kbd>F6</kbd> and choose your sound card.

After that your sound should work properly.

Comment: That didn't fix it as the card was already selected, but I figured it out. I saw a bunch of comments say that "Auto-mute" has to be disabled.  In my case, changing it to "Line out" fixed it.  Huzzah!

Comment: ohh right forgot about that :P Glad you fixed it... :)